# Java - How to find the class an Object is part of

Tags: java

Is there any way in Java to find the class an object is part of?

```
class WrapperClass
{
    SomeObject o;
    ...
    someMethodOfWrapperClass()
    { ... }
}

[...]

SomeObject foo = new SomeObject();
WrapperClass wrap = new WrapperClass();
wrap.o = foo;
```

Is there any way to find the corresponding WrapperClass object `wrap` from *within* the SomeObject object or one of it's methods?
Something along the lines of:

```
foo.getWrapperClassObject().someMethodOfWrapperClass();
```

Thanks you very much in advance!!

Thomas

Comment: This is some pretty smelly code IMO.

Comment: Agreed. It looks like he should use inheritance instead.  But there is no way to make it work as suggested above without introducing a circular dependency between the two classes (which is bad).

Comment: My suggestion would be to ditch this design, and think why you really need this in first place. Otherwise, have a link in SomeObject class to its wrapper object.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is "no".

You could do as user robev has suggested and pass a reference to the wrapper class into `SomeObject`, but that creates a circular relationship between the two classes, `WrapperClass` is no longer *really* a wrapper class.

It begs the question of *why* you are trying to do this.

In most cases when we create a wrapper class, we are wrapping code which we have no control over, so you wouldn't normally even be able to modify SomeObject's constructor.

Have you thought of trying inheritance instead?  Maybe your `WrapperClass` should extend `SomeObject`, adding the `someMethodOfWrapperClass()` method as additional behavior.

Maybe something like this:

```
public class ExtendingClass extend SomeObject
{
    public void someMethodOfExtendingClass()
    { ... }
}

// so you can define an instance 'foo' which is ALSO an instance of SomeObject
ExtendingClass foo = new ExtendingClass();

// now you can call...
foo.someMethodOfExtendingClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a parent child relationship where SomeObject is told who its parent is, so when you do getWrapperClassObject() you'll just return the stored parent pointer.

Example constructor:

```
SomeObject(WrapperClass parent) { this.parent = parent; }
```

Comment: This is fine if you have control over SomeObject, but it doesn't make sense to wrap SomeObject in this case, why not add the needed method to SomeObject instead.  Usually we wrap a class when we have no control over its contents.  Also this creates a circular dependency.

Answer (score 1):

In SomeObject: `WrapperClass.this.someMethodOfWrapperClass();`

Comment: This doesn't even do what the original poster is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really think of a case where it makes sense to do what you are trying to do... but you might find an inner class useful in doing it...

```
class Outer
{
    Inner inner = new Inner();

    class Inner
    {
        void foo()
        {
            bar();
        }
    }

    void bar()
    {
        System.out.println("bar");
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        Outer o;

        o = new Outer();
        o.inner.foo();
    }
}
```

The answer by robev is essentially the same, but robev has the more general purpose answer (Inner has a reference to Outer in the code I posted, it is just hidden and created by the compiler).

Comment: Good point, TofuBeer, although I really don't want to encourage the original poster to use this sort of design.  It appears to me as though they need to make the wrapper class extend the original class, so that they may call the additional method.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, this is pretty suspicious code.

There are several ways to achieve it.

1. One would be to add a reference to the wrapped `SomeObject` but that leads to circular dependency like Justin pointed out.
2. Second, would be to simply make `SomeObjectWrapper extends SomeObject` but do you even have control over that part of code?
3. Last would be is to set up a convention and use reflection to get the code (the one I used is WrappedObject.name+"Wrapper"):

   ```
   package test;
   public class ObjectWrapper {
       Object o;
       public ObjectWrapper(Object o){
       this.o = o;
    }
   }


   Object o = new Object();
   String pack = "test";
   String name = package+o.getClass().getSimpleName()+"Wrapper";
   Class objWrapper = Class.forName(name);


   objWrapper.getConstructor(Object.class).newInstance(o);
   ```

But this is far too unwieldy to be of any use. For example if you make `Object o = new Integer` the whole thing will burst from exceptions.

Comment: My assumption is that he has control over the wrapper object, but not the source object.  If that is the case, option 2 will work fine.

Comment: Yeah, it would be the most logical thing; somehow the question struck the point of one designing the wrapped object and not the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't make sense. Objects aren't 'part of' classes. *References* are part of classes, but what they point to isn't. Multiple references can point to the same object. So you can't even get a unique reference for any particular object, let alone what class the reference is in.